# Verificar tempo de execução com timeit

Tags: python

Estou precisando verificar o tempo de execução de uma função usando o módulo `timeit` do Python 3, porém ele não aceita que eu passe o valor dentro da função por uma variável.

Se eu substituir a linha:

```
tempo = timeit.timeit("comp_string(string, 'Fred')", "from __main__ import
```

por

```
tempo = timeit.timeit("comp_string('Fred', 'Fred')", "from __main__ import
```

funciona, mas passando o valor `Fred` na variável não funciona.

Como eu posso corrigir isso?
Segue o código:

```
'''
Comparação de Strings por Força Bruta
'''
import timeit

def comp_string(string_new, string_origin):
    for i, c in enumerate(string_origin):
        if string_new[i] != c:
            return False
    return True

def calcula_exec(string):       
    #Calcula tempo de execução do código
    tempo = timeit.timeit("comp_string(string, 'Fred')", "from __main__ import comp_string")
    return tempo
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar incluir o valor literal do parâmetro `string` no argumetno da função `timeit` usando o método [`format()`](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/string.html#format-examples), assim:

```py
"comp_string('{0}', 'Fred')".format(string)
```

A função completa ficaria:

```
def calcula_exec(string):       
    #Calcula tempo de execução do código
    tempo = timeit.timeit("comp_string('{0}', 'Fred')".format(string), "from __main__ import comp_string")
    return tempo
```

Comment: Perfeito utluiz! Eu só não entendi o porque do {0}. E se o parâmetro fosse uma lista? É só colocar format(list)?

Comment: `{0}` seria o primeiro argumento do `format()`. No exemplo que eu dei, o método só funciona com string (`str`). Mas poderia também funcionar com um list desde que você representasse essa lista numa string, por exemplo, usando o método `join`. Se tiver `list = [1, 2, 3]`, faça `', '.join(str(i) for i in list)`.